# Does doping and size determine the characteristics of a semi-conductor?

Tags: electric-current, semiconductor-physics, voltage

Does the maximum voltage and current that a semiconductor can withstand (without being damaged) depend upon the size and doping of the semiconductor?

If so, then please explain,

1.What is the reason that causes them to vary?

2.How to they vary?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Doping increases the free electrons (as well as holes) in the semiconductor. So it can increase the current through it (by decreasing the resistance). But it has a limit, over which the overlapped part between "n" and "p" will be damaged.

When extra current will flow, the conductor will face Joule heating, so more thermally exited electrons will arise. Thus the conductor will face zener break down. 
 So doping can increase those facts but not for long time.